# PHP CLI - Unauthorized access to memory SIGSEGV

Tags: php, memory, command-line-interface, segmentation-fault

I have problem with PHP import script to MySQL database. When I run PHP script from terminal, after about 500 inserts, php shudown and return:

Unathorized access to memory SIGSEGV.

I have:

PHP 5.3
MySQL 5.1.54-1ubuntu4
Ubuntu 11.04

Thanks for help!

Comment: Without seeing your code, impossible to answer. But since PHP provides no mechanism to manage memory at low levels, this error could only be caused by PHP itself or one of the loaded modules. A resource leak perhaps.

Comment: I think that on the PHP source code isn't something, what help in this, because on another computer with Windows + Apache + same PHP/MySQL this import script work fine .. I think that error is in  allocated memory / timelimit etc. I dont know, but Linux probably restrict to much mysql requests.

Comment: perhaps, but if you showed the code i'm sure we could recommend  how to alter it to use less memory in the first place. you should also look at how much memory is allocated to php on both machines, and use php's own functions to show memory useage.

Comment: The script is to single use, I need only convert some data between tables (database of streets, cityparts etc. so its large data tables). So this source isn't optimalizated :) And this code is built up on Nette framework with notORM database layer, so refactoring code doesnt important. Now, I reinstalled all php, apache packages, but still same ;( ... and memory usage return (ater error) 46MB

Comment: I tried a "memory test" with:

  $a = "";
  while (1) {
   $a .= str_repeat(".", 100);
   echo memory_get_usage() . "\n";
   usleep(10);
  }

And its OK (end with err memory limit 128Mb, so its correct).

Comment: single use or not, your clearly expecting psychic support.

Comment: $citypart = $this->db->loc_citypart()->where("loc_continent_id", 0);
        foreach ($citypart as $tmp) { 
   $city = $this->db->loc_city[$tmp["loc_city_id"]]; 
            $tmp["loc_continent_id"] = $city["loc_continent_id"];
            $tmp["loc_country_id"] = $city["loc_country_id"];
            $tmp["loc_region_id"] = $city["loc_region_id"];
            $tmp["loc_district_id"] = $city["loc_district_id"];
            $tmp->update();
   echo memory_get_usage() . "\n";
        }

Comment: But I said that it's use notORM + Nette, so from this source code you cant see something interesting :) ... I separated this method to own PHP part (without loading unused class) and now It's terminated without any ERROR .. but still after about 500 updates (but it excepted more than 80 thousand updates).

Comment: so when I trying run still again, once I see error "Unathorized access to memory SIGSEGV" or usually "zend_mm_heap corrupted".

Comment: I found solution .. error is in notOrm class NotORM_Cache_Session which provide session cache for select part of queries.

Answer (score 0):

Glad you found the error:

> I found solution .. error is in notOrm class NotORM_Cache_Session which provide session cache for select part of queries.

Expanding on that to help others who might be experiencing similar errors, you will get segfault errors when using PHP sessions if `session.save_path` in php.ini is not writeable or readable.

To solve, edit the `session.save_path` line in php.ini to

```
session.save_path = "/var/lib/php/session"
```

And run this in terminal:

```
chmod 755 /var/lib/php/session
```

If you're running PHP from root you may also have to add:

```
chown root /var/lib/php/session
```